# how to find direction of device movement?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iphone application in which i want to find direction of device on movement.I dont know how to find.Can u help me for this query.Thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're speaking about heading.  This will only work in the iPhone 3GS and the upcoming models.

Call the `startUpdatingHeading` method on your location manager, and implement

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading`

to retrieve the heading from the manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compass direction the iPhone is travelling on a map, go with dc's answer. If you want to detect shaking and movement of the iPhone, use the accelerometer:

You create a class, or specify a class as the `<UIAccelerometerDelegate>`, and then implement the didAccelerate method. The class could be your existing viewcontroller, for example.

Inside this method, you can detect in which direction 'gravity pulls' relative to the bottom, left, and in/out axes by checking acceleration.x, .y, and .z, respectively. Each axis will have a measure from 0.0 to 1.0, and together they form a vector with length 1 that points in the direction of gravity pull, essentially the angle at which it's held. When lying face up on a table, for example, the pull will be in the +Z direction ('into the screen' axis).

This is when the iPhone is a body at rest. If the iPhone is shaken, the vector length deviates from 1.0. You can calculate the vector length with the Pythagorean theorem, simply `l = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);`

To start the accelerometer measurements, use this code

```
UIAccelerometer *acc=[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
acc.delegate=self;
acc.updateInterval=1/60;
```

If you want to poll it 60 times per second. Simple and fun :)